# Error: "The function appears with no arguments" Trouble trying to solve differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to compute the following system of differential equations:

```
DSolve[
{
x'[t]==x[t] (2+2 x[t]^2-y[t]^2-y[t] (2+z[t])+x[t] (-4+y[t]+z[t])),
y'[t]==-y[t] (1-2 x[t]^2+y[t]^2+y[t] (-2+z[t])-x[t] (y[t]+z[t]))
}, {x[t],y[t],z[t]},t]
```

And it's not working. It's not clear why, it says:

> DSolve::dvnoarg: The function x appears with no arguments.

Trying the following example to find what I typed wrong:

> [image]

And then, I tried:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]}, {y, z}, x]

DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]}, {y[x], z[x]}, x]
```

But it gave the same error:

> DSolve::dvnoarg: The function y appears with no arguments.

It's not clear what's happening.

Comment: you have more dependent variables than odes.

Comment: @Nasser But what is happening in the example I mentioned? In the Mathematica help file, it is computed but I can't compute it.

Comment: Your first example does not work. The rest works. Start with clean kernel and run your first example again, you should get an error `There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is  underdetermined` Look carefully at your equations. You only have two equations but three dependent variables specified. `x[t],y[t],z[t]`.  I do know why you get `The function x appears with no arguments.`. If you start with clean kernel this should not be the error.